# Передать значение checkbox методом POST в цикле

Tags: php

Добрый день. Есть одна проблема. Делаю опросник на php.

Есть две таблицы в базе данных:

1) `polls`(вопросы) - содержит 2 строки `id` и `title`.

2) `poll_answer`(варианты ответов) - содержит 4 строки `id`, `poll_id`, `title`, `votes`.

Из базы все вытаскиваю вот так:

```
    $query=mysqli_query($db,"select * from poll_answer p1 LEFT JOIN polls p2 ON p1.poll_id=p2.id_p ORDER BY p1.poll_id ");
    $polls_id=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        if ($row["id_p"] != $polls_id) {
            $polls_id = $row["id_p"];
            echo '<div class="poll"> <b> ' . $row["title_polls"] . ' <br> ';
        }
        #echo $row["title"] . '<br> <hr>';
        echo '<label> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="' . $row["id"] . '">' . $row["title"] . ' </label><br>';

    }
    echo '<form action="polls_result.php" method="post">' .
    '<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="view_res"
        value="Result">' . '<input type="submit" name="vote" id="vote" value="Vote">' .
    '</form>';
```

Проблема в том, что не могу передать значение checkbox(отмеченные) методом POST на сторону обработчика `polls_result.php`.

Comment: input type="checkbox" выводите внутри формы, а не перед ней. Или используйте атрибут form https://webref.ru/html/input/form

Comment: Думаю внутри цикла не получится использовать form

Comment: Форму открываете перед циклом, потом в цикле выводите инпуты и после цикла закрываете форму.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас чекбоксы вне формы, просто переместите цикл генерации чекбоксов внутрь формы.

```
$query=mysqli_query($db,"select * from poll_answer p1 LEFT JOIN polls p2 ON p1.poll_id=p2.id_p ORDER BY p1.poll_id ");
$polls_id=0;
echo '<form action="polls_result.php" method="post">' .
'<div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="view_res"
    value="Result">';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ($row["id_p"] != $polls_id) {
        $polls_id = $row["id_p"];
        echo '<div class="poll"> <b> ' . $row["title_polls"] . ' <br> ';
    }
    #echo $row["title"] . '<br> <hr>';
    echo '<label> <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="' . $row["id"] . '">' . $row["title"] . ' </label><br>';

}
echo '<input type="submit" name="vote" id="vote" value="Vote">' .
'</form>';
```